# Is WPF required to learn XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am planning to learn XAML. I wanted to know if I should first learn about WPF and then start XAML?
Please advice.

Comment: What do you plan to do with XAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what your future plans are with XAML/WPF. If you want to get up and running and use it as quick as possible you might consider starting with XAML and WPF at the same time (but note that you can't learn or use WPF just be learning about XAML).

If you plan to work with XAML/WPF for a long time and you will have a lot of WPF projects ahead you probably should consider starting with "pure" WPF.

I belong to the latter camp and it helped me a lot to first get to know the WPF object model, rendering and layout system and then start with XAML, styles, templates etc. For me it made thinks easier to understand (and there is a ***lot*** to understand). I understood that XAML is just another way to represent/serialize a .NET object graph that is built as a layer on top.
This is also the way [Charles Petzold's book](http://charlespetzold.com/wpf/) is structured and I think it is the perfect book to start with when you want to get to know WPF really well.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. I needed some guidance to start. Guess I will start with WPF and after few days start XAML too.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good question but WPF applications are is built on XAML. I started learning from [WPFTUTORIAL](http://www.wpftutorial.net)

Answer (score 0):

You will find that you will are likely to learn **both** at the same time. That said, `XAML` is a designed to be a mark-up language and is used for several technologies, e.g. WPF and WCF et. al.

As [@bitbonk mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588587/is-wpf-required-to-learn-xaml/7588613#7588613), several books on the subject first give you an introduction to WPF (Dependency Objects, Visual Tree and Logical Tree, Controls, etc) before showing any XAML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do make sure that your first 2 or 3 applications are throw away apps (not production code).  I have seen way too many developers code themselves into a hole when learning to code with WPF.  I would recommend studying the MVVM pattern as well.  This is critical to building stable WPF applications.

Here are some blog posts I have written that may be of some assistance.

http://tsells.wordpress.com/category/mvvm/